# Detect private browsing FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser

### How can I detect private browsing FireFox on javascript?

---

Firefox ver. 29.0.1

Checking indexedDB in try...catch dont' work :(

http://jsfiddle.net/ejmcLuar/

```js
    var dbTest;
    try{    
        dbTest =  window.indexedDB.open('test');
        console.log('Incognito NOT detected')
    } catch(e){
        console.log('Incognito detected')
    }
```

Comment: you can't reliably tell the difference between a first-time visitor and a regular in private mode, but there may be some supporting clues; lack of cookies, lack of referrer, ajax timing differences, etc. none of those mean private mode, but they can prove non-private mode.

Comment: You can use:

var dbTest = window.indexedDB.open('test');
dbTest.onerror = function() {
  isPrivateModeFF= true;
}

But it will be asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is simple: There is no sure way to detect if a user is private browsing or not.